# Manually fill C# List of collection of datatypes

Tags: c#, list, properties

I am working on a C# example to learning the Lists and how to initialize them. So I have a classes with some properties:

```
public class C1
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public List<StatusChoices> ChoiceList { get; set; }

    ...

    public string FillList(string v1, int v2, bool v3)
    {
        // How can I fill this.ChoiceList?

        this.ChoiceList.val1 = v1; //Is this possible?

        return this.ChoiceList.val1;
    }
}

public class StatusChoices
{
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public int val2    { get; set; }
    public bool val3   { get; set; }
}
```

This is probably easy, but I wasn't able to achieve it so far. How can I add some values "**manually**" to the list?

Comment: please refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to use one of the methods that add an element to the list, the most straighforward one being `Add(StatusChoices item)`. You can only add instances of the `StatusChoices` class since you specialized `ChoiceList` on that.

Comment: If you declare variable of type **List<StatusChoices>** then you can only add instances of object of type StatusChoices to it. Just read about the Add method in the [_List<T>_ documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ChoiceList` is initialized to `null` when the class `C1` is created. (In fact every class field, including hidden property backing fields, is initialized to its default value.)  You must create the list object explicitly.

You can do so in the class constructor

```
public class C1
{
    ...
    public List<StatusChoices> ChoiceList { get; set; }

    public C1() // Constructor. Is run when a new C1 object is created with `new`.
    {
        ChoiceList = new List<StatusChoices>();
    }

    ...
}
```

After creation, this list is empty. You must add elements to it:

```
public string FillList(string v1, int v2, bool v3){
    ChoiceList.Add(new StatusChoices{ val1 = v1, val2 = v2, val3 = v3 });
    return v1;
}
```

Note that you have to create a `StatusChoices` object as well. You can think of a class as being a template that can be used to create objects.

When you have added objects to the list, you can access them by enumeration

```
foreach (StatusChoices sc in ChoiceList) {
    Console.WriteLine($"val 1 = {sc.val1}, val 2 = {sc.val2}, val 3 = {sc.val3}")
}
```

or through indexing

```
StatusChoices first = ChoiceList[0];
StatusChoices second = ChoiceList[1];
string v1_of_first  = first.val1;
string v1_of_second  = second.val1;
```

You can also access properties of the elements directly

```
string v1_of_first  = ChoiceList[0].val1;
string v1_of_second  = ChoiceList[1].val1;
```

If you have an object `C1 c1 = new C1();`, you can write

```
string v = c1.ChoiceList[0].val1;
```

You could even construct a list of `C1` objects

```
var mainList = new List<C1>(); // The var-keyword lets C# infer the type.
                               // This saves you from writing List<C1> again.
mainList.Add(new C1());
mainList.Add(new C1());
mainList.Add(new C1());
mainList[0].FillList("a", 12, true);
mainList[0].FillList("b", 33, false);
mainList[1].FillList("x", 77, true);
...
string v = mainList[1].ChoiceList[2].val1;
```

---

I used `ChoiceList.Add(new StatusChoices{ val1 = v1, val2 = v2, val3 = v3 });` to add a new element to the list. This is a short version of

```
StatusChoices sc = new StatusChoices();
sc.val1 = v1;
sc.val2 = v2;
sc.val3 = v3;
ChoiceList.Add(sc);
```

The short version uses an object initializer `{ val1 = v1, ... }`.

Comment: Well done @olivier-jacot-descombes for the detailed explanation

Comment: Thank you Olivier!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
public string FillList(string v1, int v2, bool v3){
    this.ChoiceList = new List<StatusChoices> {
     new StatusChoices { val1 = v1, val2 = v2, val3 = v3, } };
    return this.ChoiceList[0].val1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an instance of the StatusChoices class, initialize it and add it to the list.

(I added lazy initialization of the List)

```
public class C1{
    public string p1 {get; set; }
    public string p2 {get; set; }
    public List<StatusChoices> ChoiceList { get; set; }
    ...
    public string FillList(string v1, int v2, bool v3){

        if(ChoiceList == null)
        {
            this.ChoiceList = new List<StatusChoices>();
        }

        var newItem = new StatusChoices {val1 = v1, val2 = v2, val3 = v3};
        this.ChoiceList.Add(newItem);

        return newItem.val1;
    }
}
```